# ReferenceError get's thrown at me because: Cannot access 'DurationFormatter' before initialization

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

And like the other post I did, I'll get straight to the point. So I get an error because of some sort, but I can see no mistake in my code, so that is why I am here, I am quite weirded out by this.
(This is a slash command)
Here is the code:

```
const { version } = require("discord.js");
const { codeBlock } = require("@discordjs/builders");
const { DurationFormatter } = new DurationFormatter();

exports.run = async (client, interaction) => {
  const duration = DurationFormatter.format(client.uptime);
  const stats = codeBlock("asciidoc", `= STATISTICS =
• Men Usage   :: ${(process.memoryUsage().heapUsed / 1024 / 1024).toFixed(2)}
• Uptime      :: ${duration}
• Users       :: ${client.guilds.cache.map(g => g.memberCount).reduce((a, b) => a + b).toLocaleString()}
• Servers     :: ${client.guilds.cache.size.toLocaleString()}
• Channels    :: ${client.channels.cache.size.toLocaleString()}
• Discord.js  :: v${version}
• Node        :: ${process.version}`);
  await interaction.reply(stats);
};

exports.commandData = {
  name: "stats",
  description: "Show's the bots stats",
  options: [],
  defaultPermissions: true,
};

exports.guildOnly = false;
```

Here is where the error gets thrown:

```
ERROR Unhandled rejection: ReferenceError: Cannot access 'DurationFormatter' before initialization
ReferenceError: Cannot access 'DurationFormatter' before initialization
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\emilb\OneDrive\Desktop\Tap\slash\stats.js:3:31)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:94:18)
    at init (C:\Users\emilb\OneDrive\Desktop\Tap\index.js:41:21)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\emilb\OneDrive\Desktop\Tap\index.js:63:1)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with the statement `const { DurationFormatter } = new DurationFormatter();`?

Comment: Hmm `const { DurationFormatter } = new DurationFormatter()`... how does this make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

```
const { DurationFormatter } = new DurationFormatter();
```

will never work. Here's what that line tells the JavaScript engine to do:

1. Upon entry the the scope, declare a local constant called `DurationFormatter`, reserving that identifier in the current scope, without *initializing* it (which means you can't read its value; it has no value to read yet, not even `undefined`).
2. When the step-by-step execution reaches that statement, evaluate the initializer expression `new DurationFormatter()`.
3. Initialize the constant from step #1 with the value resulting from step #2.

Your code throws an error at step #2 (`new DurationFormatter()`) because you can't read the value of `DurationFormatter` (the constant declared in step #1), because it has never been initialized.

Comment: So basically just delete it...

Comment: That depends on [what you were trying to do with it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69559343/referenceerror-gets-thrown-at-me-because-cannot-access-durationformatter-bef#comment122949145_69559343). `new DurationFormatter()` suggests it's a constructor function. `const { DurationFormatter } =` suggests you were trying to grab a property called `DurationFormatter` from the instance being created. It would be odd for the result of that (if it worked) to be the original constructor function.